# Route53 - Ping Private Hosted Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have created the following resources:

- VPC with the custom DHCP options (Screenshot below)
- Route53 - Private Hosted zone with `xyz.local`
- Attached VPC to Hosted Zone
- Two EC2 instances (CentOS) inside the VPC created above
- `A` record under Private Hosted Zone pointing to each EC2 Instance (ec21.xyz.local, ec22.xyz.local)[image: DHCP Option]

Here is the output of my `dig` command:

[image]

But when I do `ping xyz.local`, I am not able to ping it.
As per my understanding, I should be able to ping it.

Please correct my understanding here and help me to understand what else I have missed.

Comment: Have you added rules to allow `ICMP` in the Security Group 'inbound' rules attached to the instances?

Comment: I can ping google.com, so I don't think this might be a issue

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 instances only permit **inbound** access if there is a matching rule in a **Security Group** associated with the instance.

To allow incoming 'ping' request, you will need to add a rule that permits `ICMP` traffic in the Inbound rules list:

[image: Security Group ICMP rule]

This will allow the request to reach the instance. The instance will be able to return the response because Security Groups are *stateful*.

Comment: I have allowed all of the traffic in Inbound and Outbound. I doubt is it possible to ping the root domain since it does not point to any location?

Comment: @ShivkumarMallesappa Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. When pinging a DNS Name, the name is first resolved to an IP address (which will be displayed on-screen by the Ping command). Then, the `ping` command will ping that IP address. If you have not configured the domain name, then it cannot resolve to an IP address, and therefore it will be unable to send an ICMP request to a destination.

Comment: Hey John, I have created a Private Hosted Zone under Route53, as of now, it does not contain any entries (A Record), etc, under that. Basically `xyz.local` is the root and I am trying to ping `xyz.local`. Is it possible to ping the root domain? Apologies for the confusions.

Comment: It is not possible to ping a "domain". Rather, the domain must resolve to an IP address, and it is the computer at that IP address that receives the ICMP (ping) request. If you have not added any records under the domain, then it will not resolve to an IP address and any ping attempt will fail.

Comment: Thank you John for clearing my doubt. Please post this as an answer.